# Apostrophes not coming through in .po file

Tags: php, poedit

I am translating with poedit. However poedit seems to be ignoring apostrophes. For example **shouldn't** is coming through as **shouldnt**. I am encoding in utf-8. Does anyone know why this is the case and if there is a solution ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use the html entity: `&#8217;`

Source: http://geektnt.com/tag/poedit

Some text characters need to be converted into html entities otherwise they will not display correctly. A very common example is a word containing an apostrophe or single quote (‘) which needs to be replaced with `&#8217;` — for example, Chloe O’Brian should be written as `Chloe O&#8217;Brian`. For a complete list of html entities, visit W3Schools.

Comment: Would this be the correct way to format ? echo __(' shouldn&#8217;t', $jwp_lang[basictheme'])?>

Comment: I'm not sure since I don't know wordpress and wordpress's functions.

Comment: Ok no problem , but within poedit should it come through as &#8217;  or '

Comment: This is completely wrong. There's absolutely no reason to use HTML entities when translating (what a horrible user experience) — provided, of course, that you use the gettext API correctly *on the WordPress side*.

Answer (score 1):

I assure you that Poedit isn't somehow ignoring or eating apostrophes — that's preposterous. It's just an editor that puts whatever you wrote, exactly as you wrote it (yes, including `'` or any Unicode characters), into your PO and MO files.

Your problem is *in your PHP code* where you incorrectly escape the (translated) strings before printing them — how and in what context you do that is unfortunately something you didn't share.

But this is why e.g. WordPress has functions like [esc_attr_e](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr_e) that do any necessary escaping and do it correctly, so that you don't have to do anything ridiculous (and painful to work with!) like substituting `'` with `&#8217;` in all your translations (which wouldn't even work when using untranslated text…).